# jquery alert window not working

Tags: jquery

I am a jquery noob.  That is I'm getting started learning jquery.  As an exercise, I'm trying to get an alert when I click a button, but the script does not perform the desired function. What is wrong with the example?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#ResetButton').submit(function () {
        alert('Hello');
    })
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" value="Reset" name="ResetButton"  id="ResetButton" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `click` instead of `submit`.

Comment: Check your browser console. What error messages do you see? More importantly, **it seems like you have not loaded jQuery** (especially if you see the message `Uncaught ReferenceError: (...)`).

Comment: Why did you use `submit` instead of `click` ?

Comment: @RicardoAlvaroLohmann I tried click first.  it did not work, so I was guessing. I believe Terry is correct.

Comment: @Terry  This is the error: the error I'm getting is GET http://localhost:60132/Scripts/NewHome/jquery-2.0.1.min.map 500 (Internal Server Error), so it seems you are correct.

Comment: Note that if you want to handle a form submit, you should use the submit event, not a click event on a submit button. Just don't forget to prevent the default form submit if that's what you want to do. If you use click instead, it won't catch a user pressing enter on the input to submit the form.

Comment: have you check you are loading the jquery library?, check on the source to see if you are getting its code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `submit` is more for forms being submitted, if you want to track the click event of the input button you can change `submit` to `click`. The other option is to wrap your form elements within a form element and then change the selector of `submit` to the form ID like in this example.

**HTML**

```
<form id="formId">
<input type="submit" value="Reset" name="ResetButton"  id="ResetButton" />
</form>
```

**javascript**

```
$(function () {
    $('#formId').submit(function () {
        alert('Hello');
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ngwed77z/

Comment: I also need to load jquery <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('#ResetButton').click(function () {
        alert('Hello');
    })
});
```

whenever you click a tag with id "ResetButton", jquery will perform the function.

if you want to make the submit way, then you might need to make a form.

```
<form id="theForm">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="test">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#theForm').submit(function(){
        // Your code
    });
</script>
```

in this case, you will need to select the form instead of button.